# Putting semicolons after while and if statements in C++

Tags: c++

How come in C++ when you put:

```
while (expression);
```

the while loop doesn't run no matter if the expression is true or not.

However if you put:

```
if (expression);
```

the statement runs no matter if the expression is true or not.

It seems like they should both behave the same way.

Comment: They *do* behave the same way, although if the while loop is infinite it might take kind of a long time to reach the next statement.

Comment: Both constructs "run", i.e., `expression` gets evaluated. Depending on the side effects of evaluating `expression` or whether `expression` involves `volatile` variables, the outcome may vary.

Comment: Section 1.10.24 of the c++ standard allows the compiler to remove the while loop entirely without proving it is not infinite under certain circumstances.

Answer (score 15):

Your statement that gets run (or not) is an empty statement, the `;`. The other statements that follow the `;` have nothing to do with your if- and while-statement. Your code would do the same when written as

```
while (expression)
{
    ;
}
```

and

```
if (expression)
{
    ;
}
```

The only difference is that your statement would be inside a block. You could add more statements inside the block (inside the curly brackets) that would get executed, if the expression was true.

Comment: So in this simple example i would expect the contents of the if statement to run no matter what.     // Pressure control
    if (50 < House_Pressure < 70);{
       digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
    }                                                  would that be correct?

Answer (score 5):

The syntax is:

```
if (<expr>) <statement>

// or

while (<expr>) <statement>
```

So the statement (in both cases) is only executed if the expression evaluates to true. In the case of `while` it will enter a loop (re-evaluating express each time).

So the question what `<statement>` is executes. This comes down to the definition of statement. If there are not braces `{}` then the next statement is terminated by `;` even if that statement is **EMPTY**. An **empty** statement is valid;

```
if (<expr>)    /* Empty Statement */;

while (<expr>) /* Empty Statement */;
```

In both cases there is nothing being executed (after the expression is evaluated). Though `while` may enter an infinite loop. Note: '{}' is a statement-Block (a type of statement (that contains a list of other statement).

Note:

It is considered bad form to use empty statements with `for(;;)` or `while()` or `if()`. It is often hard to spot and when people do spot it they are not entirely sure the code is correct (and may have to spend time de-bugging the code to verify correctness).

I find it best to use '{}` after each of these to emphasis the point (and catch multi=statement macros).

```
for(<init>;<test>;<inc>) { /*Deliberately blank */ }
```

Answer (score 4):

actually when you put

```
while(expr);
```

then if `expr` is true then you get into an infinite loop that will never end (so the remaining code never executes)

you can understand it by replacing the empty statement `;` with a no-op

```
void noop(){}

while(expr)noop();
```

then the semantics make sense

Comment: Ok that makes sense, although I still don't see why if(expr); should run when it's false while while(expr); doesn't run when it is false.

Comment: because the block after the `if(expr);` is not part of the if anymore. that's also why `if(expr);{...}else{...}`is a compiler error

Comment: But shouldn't that mean then the block after while is no longer part of it and thus should also run?

Comment: @pajamas yes it does, when expr is false then it will run

Comment: @pajamas: If `expr` evaluates to 0 (a false value), then `if (expr);` and `while (expr);` do the same thing: they evaluate `expr` and do nothing else. After that, any immediately following statements are executed.

Comment: The loop doesn't _have_ to be infinite if the expression has side effects or references — directly or indirectly — memory that is modified from another thread.

Answer (score 1):

They both run, as has been pointed out in other answers.

Consider the canonical string concatenator `while(*s1++ = *s2++);` once `s1` and `s2` have been initialized. `expr` in this case is `*s1++ = *s2++`, and the body of the while loop is the empty statement `;`. Remember that in C, the value of an assignment is the assigned value, so this could be rewritten as

```
while((*s1++ = *s2++) != 0)
{
}
```

and have the same effect (with possible variations in performance depending on optimizations performed by the compiler).

Your confusion likely does stem from the fact that `if` and `while` are both followed either by a single statement, or a single statement block. When you put a semicolon statement terminator after the condition part, they become semantically equivalent to:

```
while(expr)
{
}
{
    /* do something */
}
```

and

```
if(expr)
{
}
{
    /* do something */
}
```

which are both perfectly valid code (you can have an empty block, or a block without an associated flow control statement) but probably don't do what you want.

**If `expr` is constant**, which is often the case when no constituent variables are modified inside the (empty) loop, then the while loop will either skip the empty statement block (if `expr` evaluates to false) or turn into an infinite loop executing the empty statement (if `expr` evaluates to true).

You can check this by giving `expr` a non-breaking side effect, such as logging a message or increment some internal static or member state variable:

```
while(log_message(), expr);
```

and observe that the log_message() function gets called repeatedly.

Assuming that your code is something like:

```
int x = 0;
while (x < 1234);
{
    x++;
}
/* do more... */
```

it should now be obvious why your program doesn't do what you expect, as the above is semantically equivalent to:

```
int x = 0;
while (x < 1234)
{
}
{
    x++;
}
/* do more... */
```

Since `x` never gets modified inside the while loop's statement block (because it is empty), the expression `x < 1234` will never evaluate to anything other than true, and hence you have an infinite loop. If the expression was instead `x != 0` the empty statement block would instead be skipped over because the while loop's condition evaluates to false, you would reach the `x++` and end up with `x == 1` at the point of `/* do more... */`.

If the condition was instead something like `++x < 1234`, then `x` would simply be incremented (`++x` evaluated), *and the empty statement-block executed*, until the condition is true, after which the while loop finishes and execution continues with a single pass through what you *intended* to do a number of times.